# Проблема с импортом модуля PIL

Tags: python

Рабочие среды не видят PIL, Image.

```
No module named PIL(Image)
```

На компьютере стоит последний пакет Anaconda.
Пробовал как устанавливать `Pillow`, так и обновлять. Все равно не хочет работать. 
С VS Code то же самое.

Comment: `pip install pillow` и `import PIL`. Если это не работает, то скорее всего у вас несколько версий питона и в одну вы установили `pillow`, а у другой пытаетесь провести импорт

Comment: Покажите саму строчку импорта, на которую ругается.

Comment: Если вы обновляете средствами анаконды, она у вас установлена для всех пользователей, и у вас windows, попробуйте сделать это от имени администратора.